# Laravel: get an item that exists a given number of times on database?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table named contact. In that table, there is a column named phone number.

What I really want to do is get a phone number that exists 2 or 3 times on the table. Is there any way to do that using eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `having count`:

```
$numbers = DB::table('contact')
    ->select('phone_number')
    ->groupBy('phone_number')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(phone_number) > 1')
    ->get();
```